# Prevent hosted video from being easily downloaded

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video

I am running a small video website (~1000 hosted videos). Run it using PHP, also have freedom to use any server-side dependencies (e.g. ffmpeg).

Originally I had an `.htaccess` set-up to prevent hotlinking/direct downloads:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://original.url/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.original.url/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(mp4|mp3|avi)$ - [F]
```

Unfortunately due to performance/delivery speed issues I had to move my media to a Storage/CDN (picked Digital Ocean Spaces due to cost).

However, the unpleasant surprise was that the storage had no functionality to restrict access by referrer's IP. They have expiring URLs which takes care of hotlinking issue, yet the problem with direct downloads still bothers me. Giving a URL to a user to download the video in such a straightforward manner is a real vulnerability imho. They at least have to jump through hoops.

I am a developer myself but the whole video topic is a relatively new territory for me.

Googling for a right solution (and also checking how other websites, e.g. Youtube work) gave me the only reasonable option:

stream videos from binary data (similar to youtube and many others). However, in order to do this efficiently I probably need to convert each video into a set of small chunks/segments (each of my vids is ~100mbs).

Would it make sense to come up with my own technical solution (e.g. splitting video into segments after encoding it with FFMPEG, with MPEG-DASH, for instance) and using an HTML5 based player that can play such format out-of-the box?

Is there a good tutorial for that? Going through multiple posts on stackoverflow did not get any exact step-by-step guide.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if a video is available to stream, there is no effective way to prevent it being downloaded.

There are various hurdles you can put in place like expiring or obsfucatyed urls, but ultimately the video has to arrive at the device to be played and their are many tools and well documented approaches to capture a streamed video.

For this reason, most streaming services that want to avoid content being copied and re-distributed encrypt the content and use a DRM system to securely share the decryption keys only with entitled users.

Most DRM's will allow polices to be set also on expiry, whether the content can be played over HDMI, the resolution for a particular devices etc.

Some video may even be copied by pointing a camera at the screen while it is playing back, although quality is not usually great with this approach. In cases like this, tracing the leak to its source usually becomes the focus and forensic watermarking may be used - essentially hiding an invisible watermark in the video that can help identify the source of the leak.

On your question around developing your own streaming tech solution - video streaming is a complex and specialised area, with many standards that usually have to be supported across multiple devices types so it is usually easier to leverage existing specialised streaming servers - there are quite a few guides using open source solutions that you can look at to get a feel for the ares - e.g. : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use Google Widevine and Apple Fairplay DRM encrypted service provider services like Vdocipher. They are not able to save your video from piracy on a browser but on the app and other streaming interfaces, they work.